# How can I get the number of share for a post on a fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, fan-page

I know how I can retrieve impressions, like and comment but I've never found how can I retrieve the "share".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've found something but I'm not sure if it's documented. When you access to a post with its post id via the graph API you have an endpoint /insigths.